# Overlaying a network graph on a latitude vs Local time plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have a set of nodes with latitude and local time coordinates for each node. I want to overlay the network created from the adjacent matrix on a polar plot, where the circles represents latitude and the angle represents the time. [image: Something like this.]

For the attached image below, (f) is 12. I also want the grid rotated such that 0 is on the right (where 6 currently is). I'm new to using networkx and I've been having  a tough go of it so far.

This is what I've tried so far but with just a few points.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


adj_matrix = [
    [0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0]
]

node_positions = {
    0: (45, 1),   
    1: (30, 2),   
    2: (60, 3),  
    3: (75, 4)   
     }

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(np.array(adj_matrix))


pos = {node: (np.radians(lat), mlt) for node, (lat, mlt) in node_positions.items()}

# Create the polar grid
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

# Plot the polar grid for latitude vs MLT
for lat in range(0, 90, 15):  # Plotting latitude lines at intervals of 15 degrees
    ax.plot(np.radians(range(24)), [lat] * 24, linestyle='--', lw=1, color='black')


# Draw the circular network layout on the polar grid
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=5, node_color='skyblue', font_weight='bold')

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edge_color='gray')

plt.title("Circular Grid Network Overlay on Polar Grid (Lat vs LT)")
plt.show()
```

And here's the result of that code. [image: Trial result]